# Dropdown menu remain open after click and refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have a problem on how to make my dropdown remain open after clicking and avoid closing after refresh.

Here's what I've done.

```
<button class="dropdown_btn">
   <span>Sample</span>
</button>
<div class="dropdown-container">
   <a href="sample.php">Sample 1</a>
   <a href="sample.php">Sample 2</a>
</div>
<br>
<button class="dropdown_btn">
  <span>Sample</span>
</button>
<div class="dropdown-container">
   <a href="sample.php">Sample 1</a>
   <a href="sample.php">Sample 2</a>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/Mandy201/7w8t2muc/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `localStorage` with a simply flag. On open the flag become true, on close the flag become false. For the refresh you need to test your `var` contains in `localStorage`. If is true, display the menu, if is false do not display the menu

Comment: How can I properly implement this to my code?